# Open a window on the same Site with jQuery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Sorry for my English...

[image: how to show the image]

What I want is, when someone clicks the zoom icon, it opens a small window in the Site and in this small window I describe a product.

The code from the image

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

         <div class="col"> 

          <div class="product-grid">

                <div class="product-image">
                   <a class="link" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                    <img alt=""  class="bild" src="photo/111.jpg">     
                   </a> 

                </div>

                <div class="product-content">
                     <a class="links" href="/tachen_&_rucksacke/fenster/mochila_doble_tirantes-violeta.php">
                    <p class="title">Mochila doble tirantes Violeta</p>
                    </a>     

                </div>
                    <div class="price">$16.00</div>

                     <div class="div-zoom">

                   <span class="zum-warenkorb">zum warenkorb hinzufügen</span>
                   <i class="fa fa-search-plus" style="font-size: 94%; color: white; background-color:  #595959; padding: 3%;"></i>
                 </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/mezb/pen/YzyqLqy) is the code from the Site.

I use Bootstrap 4 with a Grid Layout.

What I want is, when someone clicks the zoom icon, it opens a small window in the Site and in this small window I describe a product.

[image: How I to want]

Can please someone help me and explain with easy words how to solve this problem with jQuery, Thanks

Comment: seems like you're looking for modal? https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I to tried with  **modal** and I to come to this problem... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232132/how-can-i-open-a-bootstrap-modal-beside-the-trigger-element

Comment: from that answer, you just need to inject content in the modal... for which you can use jQuery

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to does it?

Comment: here is your second question, related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272496/dynamically-injecting-content-on-bootstrap-4?noredirect=1#comment108418212_61272496

Comment: please provide valid snippet that shows your problem

Comment: My problem with Miodal I post Two days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232132/how-can-i-open-a-bootstrap-modal-beside-the-trigger-element

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you looking for modal. Bootstrap official documentation has clear and detailed guidance for your work. Follow this link.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/

NOTE: Before you use Bootstrap modals, you need to set up **jquery** and **popper.js** in your project. You need to download them seperately. Then you can use them locally in your project or use CDNs for that if you don't need to download them. This link will guide you for that.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/

Comment: Your answer is similar as I came from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252676/12999026

Comment: Bootstrap modal is the solution as you asked in this question. But the question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232132/how-can-i-open-a-bootstrap-modal-beside-the-trigger-element/61252676#61252676 you asked that pop-up window need to set beside for the item box. I hope Bootstrap pop-overs will help you. Refer this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/